# Get a set of arbitrary elements by their index

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a list of elements like:

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
  <li>h</li>
  <li>i</li>
  <li>j</li>
</ul>
```

And I have an array like this: `[ 2, 5, 6 ]`.

**(both the list of elements and this array can be quite huge, but let's keep it simple)**

How can I use jQuery efficiently to pick the elements corresponding to those elements? (in this case it would be list elements that contain `c`, `f` and `g`)

One way would be to use a jQuery `each()` and search for the index in the array. But that requires a linear search on the array for every iteration and it's not quite optimized.

Another way is to use the `eq()` selector or `eq()` function passing one index. But then I have to repeat the process for every array element and that's not efficient either. Unfortunately the `eq()` doesn't get an array as a parameter.

Another way is to write a jQuery plugin but that seems like too much work for such a small problem.

Do you know a better way that works more efficiently?

Comment: How 'bout get all list of `li` by using `var childrens = $("ul").children("li");` then you can refer to it by index like `alert(childrens[index])`

Comment: Something is going to have to loop over your array and grab each DOM element that corresponds to the number in each element of the array.  jQuery doesn't have a built-in way to do it.  So, write yourself a small function to do it yourself.  You can either make it a util function or a jQuery plug-in - your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $result = $([]); // Empty jQuery object
var $lis = $("li");
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $result = $result.add($lis.eq(array[i]));
};
```

Comment: you may have change to `$result = $result.add($lis[array[i]]);`

Answer (score 2):

You can do an indexOf of the items array to see if a item at index `idx` of `$listitems` exists.

```
var $listitems = $("<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li><li>d</li><li>e</li><li>f</li><li>g</li><li>h</li><li>i</li><li>j</li></ul>").find("li");//jQuery object of all the list items
var items = [ 2, 5, 6 ];

var $filtered = $listitems.filter(function(val, idx) {
    return $.inArray(items, idx) !== -1;
});
```

You mentioned items can be large so it may be better to convert `items` to an object

```
var itemHash = items.reduce(function(memo, item) {
    memo[item] = true;
    return memo;
}, {});
var $filtered = $listitems.filter(function(val, idx) {
    return itemHash[idx] !== undefined;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 $("ul li").eq(0) will give you the first element.
```

use the below script

```
  narray = new Array(5,6,7);
       for (i=0;i< narray.length;i++){
         $("ul li").eq(narray[i]).html('hello') //for that corresponding element
     }
```

you have to use array to get the element as this is iterative job